# Can I declare TS interfaces for use in plain JS projects with VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, visual-studio-code, typechecking

Using MS VisualCode editor, I'm trying to get some type checking. I want to keep with Javascript, but get some benefits of type checking interfaces and data structures.

According to the vscode docs I can create a `globals.d.ts` type definition file, which I did like:

```
interface QueryObj {
    input: string;
    query: string;
}

declare namespace TrainingModel {
  function preprocessQuery(qo: QueryObj): QueryObj
}
```

Then I tried to declare a function that uses this QueryObj type.

```
checkOneData (queryObj) {
    queryObj.foo = 1
```

So I was hoping to get a warning that `queryObj.foo` shouldn't be used... but nothing.

I also tried adding a JSDoc to describe the params

```
  /**
   * @param {QueryObj} queryObj
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  async checkOneData (queryObj) {
```

But this line `* @param {QueryObj} queryObj` just gives me the error `cannot find name 'QueryObj'`

I know the `.d.ts` file is being processed as I will get errors when it is incomplete.

So beyond basic parameters types like string/number, can VSCode be used in this way to somehow check user defined data structures, as we would use interfaces for in TypeScript?

refs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

Comment: Yes, yes it can. JavaScript is valid typescript.

Comment: According to the above it will not do as much as I want. I want more than built-in types checking, I want to use interfaces and structures.

Comment: According to the above it will not do as much as I want. I want more than built-in types checking, I want to use interfaces and structures.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing you can do is to set up a brand new TS project with the proper config file for TS. (just google it or youtube it, you will find this immediately. for example this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPgAXFcFHCM)

Then, inside the TS file you are working on, you are not required to write in TS. You can just code in JS and then (based on your configuration) the .ts file is compiled to vanilla JS. Then, you can just use the compiled JS file wherever you need it.

Comment: I've used TS for other projects but don't want to use it this time. The question is if VSCode will support interfaces for pure JS projects?

Comment: Check out this resource: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: yes, i included that link in the question above but it doesn't quite answer how to use TS interfaces in JS. Maybe I can bend the declaration of Object literals... https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files#object-literals-are-open-ended